# Disabled button with span still fires click function! Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, internet-explorer

I have a button, which is disabled. Inside of this button, there is also a span element. In Chrome, when the button is disabled and  is being clicked or the span is being clicked, it works as intended.

But in IE, even when the button is disabled, it still fires the click function! It's crucial for my application to not fire the click function.

Internet Explorer Version: 11.657.18362.0

HTML Code

```
  <button
    [ngClass]="['btn-x', 'btn-y--']"
    (click)="clicked($event)"
    [disabled]="disabled"
  >
    <span [style.pointer-events]="disabled ? 'none' : ''"></span>
    <span *ngIf="showCircle">
      <img src="/*****/icons/******.gif" alt="*****" class="btn-spinner" />
    </span>
  </button>
```

Angular-function

```
  clicked($event: MouseEvent) {
    if ($event.target !== $event.currentTarget && this.disabled) {
      $event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      this.onClick.emit($event);
    }
  }
```

Another problem is, that for some reason, I am not even able to use IE for debugging, therefore my opportunities are quite limited. (I am creating a new question for this).

Do you know a alternative how to prevent these function from being called, which also works for IE?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I test with your code and it throws errors: "disabled " and "onClick" doesn't exist. I edit it and make [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qx7hyw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and the button will be disabled in IE, can't be clicked. It could be better that you can provide more related code which can [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You could provide a minimal sample using online code editor like StackBlitz. So that we can have a test and check it in IE using F12 dev tools to see if there's any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <button
    [ngClass]="['btn-x', 'btn-y--']"
    (click)="clicked($event, 'DISABLED')"
    [disabled]="disabled"
  >
    <span [style.pointer-events]="disabled ? 'none' : ''"></span>
    <span *ngIf="showCircle">
      <img src="/*****/icons/******.gif" alt="*****" class="btn-spinner" />
    </span>
  </button>
```

```
    clicked($event: MouseEvent, prop) {
    if(prop === 'DISABLED')
       return;
    if ($event.target !== $event.currentTarget && this.disabled) {
      $event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      this.onClick.emit($event);
    }
  }
```

It could help with any browser but also you can implement variable that tells you if this is disabled or not!

Comment: The problem is, that this button shall only be disabled, when the parameter disabled is true. i cant pass the fixxed string 'DISABLED' into it.

Comment: ok, so pass parameter in function call `clicked($event, disabledParameter)` and check in ts file if this is true

Comment: if ($event.target !== $event.currentTarget && this.disabled) {
      $event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      this.onClick.emit($event);
    }     --> in my if statement there is already a check for the disabled variable, still tried to pass it, and the same result.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable it directly using 'true' parameter:

```
<button
[ngClass]="['btn-x', 'btn-y--']"
(click)="clicked($event)"
disabled="true">
```

If you want to disable it on some condition then wrap it like:

```
<button
[ngClass]="['btn-x', 'btn-y--']"
(click)="clicked($event)"
[disabled]=Condition1>
```

Note: Condition1 is a Boolean type variable.